# Makefile: define FAKE_* if the file FAKE_*.txt is detected

Tags: makefile

I am working on a single part of a system, and I have to cheat some measurement that I do not have (I do not have the complete system).

In the make file I added this part :

```
ifneq ("$(wildcard FAKE_FOO.txt)","")
    EndMessage += "WARNING : Version with FAKE_FOO"
    Info += FAKE_FOO
    CC_OPTS_APP += -DFAKE_FOO 
endif

ifneq ("$(wildcard FAKE_BAR.txt)","")
    EndMessage += "WARNING : Version with FAKE_BAR"
    Info += FAKE_BAR
    CC_OPTS_APP += -DFAKE_BAR 
endif
```

Then when the make command detect a file FAKE_FOO.txt it is definning FAKE_FOO. When the make command detect a file FAKE_BAR.txt it is definning FAKE_BAR.
etc...

In the code I have stuff like this :

```
#ifdef FAKE_FOO
    /* do or define my stuff, for my case */
#else
    /* do or define the normal stuff for the rest of the team */
#endif
```

This is very nice, so I can work with the same code as my team, I just need to create the file FAKE*.txt. Those file are in the ignore list so I am sure to not pollute the official repository.

I would like to avoid to edit the makefile every time I am using another FAKE_*.txt file.

How can I put this in a generic mode, in order to define FAKE_* for each FAKE_*.txt file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`foreach`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function) function and [Canned Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes):

```
define do_fake
    # Need another $(eval) call here to set the bare variable immediately
    # so the expansions on the next lines work correctly.
    $(eval bare=$(1:.txt=))
    EndMessage += "WARNING : Version with $(bare)"
    Info += $(bare)
    CC_OPTS_APP += -D$(bare)
endef

# Loop over ever FAKE_*.txt file calling the do_fake canned
# recipe/macro/define for each file.
# Use $(eval) on the result so the macro can return make statements
# and so the make parser is happy. 
$(foreach f,$(wildcard FAKE_*.txt), $(eval $(call do_fake,$f)))
```

Comment: woohoo!!! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thx so much.
There is even no syntax error ;-)